# Disable download button from iframe tag

Tags: javascript, iframe, video-streaming

Im using the [iframe tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to display videos in my site, but it keeps showing a download button (see the picture bellow) that I need to disable.

```
<iframe src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp"></iframe>
```

Is it possible to disable and to control this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should not be able to if the pages are from different domains.

It might work when the two pages are from the same domain. In this case you can try:

`window.frames[0].document.getElementById('buttonId') ...//you can use javascript or jquery to remove this elment`

Comment: There is no attribute that must be added to disable that button or some css style? There must be something I can do because if I add the attribute `allowfullscreen`, I can enable a command, in a video from a diferente domain...

Comment: Ah I see, I thought you used some custom video player. If this is HTML5 player then long story short is you can't. You can prevent user from downloading your video.